# How can I set language on google campaigns using ads-google python client library?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'm using ads-google python client library. I've faced an issue while I was creating campaign criterion which type of language. It requires me to specify language resource name on this campaign criterion type and I have no idea how to get this resource name for my chosen language.

Answer (score 1):

There's reference data available in the Google Ads API documentation. The language codes and corresponding criteria IDs can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/data/codes-formats#expandable-7).